# With all the available problems that have been categorized and their time complexities deduced, so why haven't anyone solved NP vs P yet?

Tags: time-complexity, computer-science, complexity-theory, computer-science-theory

We have problems proved to be in classes P, NP, co-NP, NP-Complete, and NP-Hard. These problems have their time complexities deduced too. I am wondering if I am missing any key information on the topic.

Comment: Problems that are in P are already by definition in NP as well. As for the NP-hard, etc., problems you mentioned, it is true that their complexity classes are proven. What's not proven is whether those classes are also part of P. They are in P if it turns out P=NP. But most CS practitioners believe P≠NP, and much complexity theory work done today does depend on that assumption — that's also true.

Comment: BTW, https://cs.stackexchange.com/ is really the place to post theory questions like this one.

Answer (score 0):

One of the standard tricks for solving this sort of problem is what's called using an "oracle".  Suppose we could ask the oracle a question about a specific class of problems, and in one step it would answer "yes" or "no".  It becomes reasonable to ask "What sort of problems are in P for a machine with this oracle"?  "What sort of problems are in NP for a machine with this Oracle.

It has been shown that there are oracles for which P=NP.  It has been shown that there are oracles for which P≠NP.  Most of the techniques we know for proving hardness should give the same result, no. matter what oracle is used.